# VBA loop code and have it recognize multiple sheets to copy to in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

[image: example]
I'm attempting to figure out IF it's possible and if so, How to run my loop so that the first time it runs it copy/pastes into Sheet1 and the second time it runs it copy/pastes into Sheet 2. I was thinking maybe an array might be helpful but I'm not familiar with their use or syntax. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
 For Each a In Range("2:2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Areas
     a.Resize(lrow - 1, a.Columns.Count).FillDown

 With Worksheets("Fall 2016")
     lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     With .Range("A3:CU" & lrow)
         On Error Resume Next
         Set erng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
         On Error GoTo 0
         If Not erng Is Nothing Then
             Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:CU"), erng.EntireRow).Copy
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial
         End If
     End With
 End With
 Next a
```

Comment: If it runs a third time would it run on `Sheet1` again, or does it run on whichever sheet isn't the `ActiveSheet`?  If you want it to just flip-flop between the two sheets even after closing and reopening I think you'll have to store a number or odd/even pairing on a sheet to check which sheet.

Comment: Is there something in your sheets which you could use to identify which sheet to paste too? Might be worth providing a screen print of the sheets?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The loop will only ever run twice. So the first time will always be sheet1 and the second time it runs will always be sheet2

Comment: @Zac Yes There should be a way to do that. The first sheet is always going to be "Lago" the Second would always be "MF". I'll post up an image what what I'm Looking at.

Comment: Also to add some context to what you're seeing in the image and with the code. The idea is that it runs the formulas then copy/pastes rows with all Errors to sheet 1. Currently it just loops so it runs the formula's from the second group (Separated by the red columns) and pastes them into Sheet 1. I want to try to get it to paste those errors on Sheet 2 instead.

Comment: @Deke - FYI, it's usually better to add information by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54008942/edit) instead of doing so in comments

Comment: Why not populate a `Queue` when the workbook open with the sheet names you need to iterate, then Dequeue when done with the name.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to set that up honestly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't see the image so I've cobbled together something that should work.
There's two procedures - `RunMe` just fires the `Test` procedure and passes it the first worksheet, the other worksheet is then considered to be the second sheet.
I haven't included the `For...Each` block as it uses `lrow` which isn't defined until after it's used, so would default to `0` - not sure what you're trying to do there.

I've added a line of code at the end of `Test` which will call itself again but passing the other sheet.

```
Sub RunMe()

    Test ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lago")

    'If not using last line in main code, then
    'include this to run second sheet at time of your choosing.
    'Test ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MF")

End Sub

Sub Test(FirstSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet

    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim eRng As Range

    If FirstSheet.Name = "Lago" Then
        'The "Parent" of a worksheet is the workbook.
        Set SecondSheet = FirstSheet.Parent.Worksheets("MF")
    Else
        Set SecondSheet = FirstSheet.Parent.Worksheets("Lago")
    End If

    With FirstSheet
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lrow, 99))
            On Error Resume Next
            Set eRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not eRng Is Nothing Then
                Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:CU"), eRng.EntireRow).Copy
                SecondSheet.Range("A3").PasteSpecial
            End If

        End With
    End With

    'Now run again but with sheets reversed.
    'Include this line to run both sheets in one go.
    If FirstSheet.Name = "Lago" Then Test SecondSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: keep getting subscript out of range error on the RunMe sub.  Everything seems to line up though so not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: That suggests you haven't got a sheet called `Lago` - if you do, check that it doesn't have any spaces before or after it on the tab name.

Comment: Names all line up. Retyped them to make sure. Moved the RunMe sub to the bottom and now getting a compile error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on the line `If FirstSheet.Name = "Lago" Then Test SecondSheet` I'm playing around with it though. I've gotta be missing something somewhere.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of - is the code in the same workbook as the worksheets you're manipulating?  `ThisWorkbook` means the workbook containing the code.  Maybe change it to `ActiveWorkbook` or `Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx")`.

Comment: That would be it, the code is being run from a module in a different workbook. (There is a lot of interaction between several workbooks). So looks like I just need to specify the workbook in the module.

Comment: That'll do it.  Just noticed in the code that the two lines `Set SecondSheet = Worksheets("MF")` and `Set SecondSheet = Worksheets("Lago")` aren't qualifying the workbook they're in, so they'll be looked for in the `ActiveWorkbook`.  I'll update the code so they look at the same workbook as the passed worksheet.